# Time sync over proxy in Windows required

Tags: windows, time

In Windows 7, I'm using a proxy server to browse the internet. It just routes http packets. I need to keep the Windows time accurate and synced with global time servers.
What's my best solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option specifically for Windows is [htp](http://www.rkeene.org/oss/htp/). I have not used it.

Another option if there are other servers in your network is to time synchronize [with them using NTP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7dc5e8f4-824a-432c-a2da-ac0e3fdf76fd/configuring-ntp-server)

Comment: i prefer the first one. because time of other computers in the network is not reliable.
anyone knows how to setup htp?

Comment: oh, u included the link. sorry, i didn't note.

Comment: You should see a check mark below the down arrow. Click that check mark.  Thanks. Your reputation will increase when you do that.